# JMeter: Capturing Throughput in Command Line Interface Mode

Tags: csv, command-line, jmeter

In Jmeter v2.13, is there a way to capture **Throughput** via non-GUI/Command Line mode?

I have the jmeter.properties file configured to output via the Summariser and I'm also outputting another [more detailed] .csv results file.

`call ..\..\binaries\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\jmeter -n -t "API Performance.jmx" -l "performanceDetailedResults.csv"`

The performanceDetailedResults.csv file provides:

- timeStamp
- elapsed time
- responseCode
- responseMessage
- threadName
- success
- failureMessage
- bytes sent
- grpThreads
- allThreads
- Latency

However, no amount of tweaking the .properties file or the test itself seems to provide Throuput results like I get via the GUI's Summary Report's *Save Table Data* button.

All articles, postings, and blogs seem to indicate it wasn't possible without manual manipulation in a spreadsheet. But I'm hoping someone out there has figured out a way to do this with no, or minimal, manual manipulation as the client doesn't want to have to manually calculate the Throughput value each time.

Answer (score 0):

It is **calculated** by [JMeter Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) so it isn't something you can enable via properties files. Same applies to other metrics which are calculated like:

- Average response time
- 50, 90, 95, and 99 [percentiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile)
- [Standard Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)

Basically throughput is calculated as simple as dividing total number of requests by elapsed time.

> **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>   The formula is: `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time)`

Hopefully it won't be too hard for you.

References:

- [Glossary #1](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [Glossary #2](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420385-Glossary)

Comment: Thanks, but I was asked by the client to have it calculated without anyone having to open in Excel and perform the calculation. I explained the simple calculation to the client, but they said "When you're not here, we want to open the log file in Excel and see the value already calculated." This was the reason for my post.

Comment: Then you can suggest 2 alternative options for them: 
1. [Graphs Generator Listener](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/)
2. [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/)

Comment: There's also [CMDRunner](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/), a command-line tool. It looks like you're already running JMeter from the command-line; depending on how you're starting those jobs, you could definitely automate it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at [JMeter-Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)?

This tool can generate aggregate report through commandline.